# dropdown box in php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am looking for a way to create a drop down list depending on what the user chooses. If the user picks the package of one profile the the output will give the user a drop down list with 1 field if the user chooses two profiles the output will give the user a drop down with 2 fields. The code recently displays just one dropdown even if the user chooses the second option

```
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu <?= empty($business) ? 'hidden' : '' ?>" aria-labelledby="business_list">
                    <?php foreach ($business as $key => $item) : ?>
                        <li><?= Html::a($item->name, ['social-manager/profiles', 'b' => $key]) ?></li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are using jQuery.You will need to define an number variable **var length** based on user selection. If user selects option 1 then **var length=1**,if user selects option 2 then **var length=2**;
Th for loop below should generate the options based on user selection.

```
for(var x=0;x<length;x++){
.....
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply 
this is the code that was produced for the drop down box 
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu <?= empty($business) ? 'hidden' : '' ?>" aria-labelledby="business_list">
                        <?php foreach ($business as $key => $item) : ?>
                            <li><?= Html::a($item->name, ['social-manager/profiles', 'b' => $key]) ?></li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do something like this is by creating API endpoint using PHP that will provide the dropdown value and then using ajax to fetch the result and repopulate the dropdown.

The flow would be like;

1. User select the profile, each time they do trigger a jquery function that will send an ajax to PHP API endpoint with the selected profile(s).
2. On the API endpoint, check how many profile is selected, return dropdown field value(s) accordingly.
3. Based on the return value, repopulate the dropdown value using jquery.